# How to match a URL with variable parts in it with Robot Framework

Tags: regex, url, robotframework

I'm trying to ensure that the browser URL, after certain operations with Robot Framework, matches a specific pattern (and has specific values) but parts of the resulting page URL change every time and those variable parts make the script fail and I can't seem to be able to get the script to pass.

Here's a hypothetical example of what I'm after:

URL: `https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=eCaTWLf0IO3k8AfGyouIBA#q=Robot+Framework`

In this URL the content of the "ei" parameter ("eCaTWLf0IO3k8AfGyouIBA") is variable. I want the script to simply ignore that parameter value and the check to pass provided other conditions (unrelated to this problem) are met. So, maybe with a regular expression, something akin to:

URL: `https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=.*#q=Robot+Framework`

How should I go about getting something like that to work?

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Do Your Stuff Here With Browser
    ${url}    Get Location
    Should Match Regexp    ${url}    https://www.google.com/.*
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did at first but that gives me:

    Google Search                                                         | FAIL |
    'https://www.google.fi/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-jSTWK_vGufk8AfaqbmQCw#q=Robot+Framework' does not match 'https://www.google.fi/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=.*#q=Robot+Framework'

Comment: Did you escaped special characters in your regexp? `\?`

Comment: Here's the exact line from the test script:

`Should Match Regexp ${url} https:\/\/www\.google\.fi\/\?gfe_rd=cr&ei=.*#q=Robot\+Framework`

Comment: I would say `/` is not special character. Try to use http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Regexp%20Escape

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work. The issue was that in Robot Framework the escape is done with double backslash ('\\') instead of just one. Changing the line to:

```
Should Match Regexp    ${url}  https://www\\.google\\.com/\\?gfe_rd=cr&ei=.*#q‌​=Robot\\+Framework
```

made the script pass.

Comment: I assume that this is actually because Robot Framework needs to escape certain characters before passing the URL string on to the SeleniumLibrary which then needs to have certain characters escaped as well, but maybe someone with more information on that could add a comment to either confirm or refute this assumption?

Comment: I think that the reason Robot Framework uses `\\\` is because of how Python  deals with it.